# Transferring data structure from R to Java

Tags: java, r

I have an R script that does some computation. The last step of the computation is a kernel density estimate: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/kerdiest/docs/kde

I now, in R, need to convert the result of calling `kde` into a string, or save it into a file, such that I can read and "unmarshal" it from a Java program.

What is the best format to use for the exchange and what R and Java libraries can read / write that format?

The structure is not ridiculously complex, but also not trivial:

```
> str(tmp)
List of 8
$ x          : num [1:1398, 1:3] 1.035 0.902 0.679 0.826 1.243 ...
 ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 .. ..$ : NULL
 .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Rb ppm" "Sb ppm" "Cr ppm"
$ eval.points:'data.frame': 1398 obs. of  3 variables:
 ..$ Rb ppm: num [1:1398] 1.035 0.902 0.679 0.826 1.243 ...
 ..$ Sb ppm: num [1:1398] -2.58 -2.6 -2.48 -2.44 -2.53 ...
 ..$ Cr ppm: num [1:1398] 4.56 4.44 4.3 4.26 4.49 ...
$ estimate   : Named num [1:1398] 0.1572 0.0897 0.0311 0.0434 0.099 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1398] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
$ H          : num [1:3, 1:3] 0.02395 0.00927 -0.014 0.00927 0.06868 ...
$ gridded    : logi FALSE
$ binned     : logi FALSE
$ names      : chr [1:3] "Rb ppm" "Sb ppm" "Cr ppm"
$ w          : num [1:1398] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
- attr(*, "class")= chr "kde"
```

Comment: Not sure if this would be of help, but you can run R from within Java code using JRI - http://rforge.net/JRI/

Comment: Good idea, but this is not an option in my case as the Java and R run on different machines.

Comment: I think JRI is the best option - you can just load the plain R data files with it - no complicated translation needed.

Comment: I don't think JRI would be an option for me as I can't install any software on the machine that runs the Java code (Java is already installed). As I understand it JRI require R libraries to be present on the system.

Answer (score 0):

[RJSONIO](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJSONIO/index.html) seems to do the job. It seems quite verbose, however.